# Change service apache2 on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04

I'm on ubuntu 12.04.

The default exe location for service apache2 (usage ex: sudo service apache2 start) currently points at /etc/apache2/bin/httpd, but that will not modify the current running apache process since init.d uses apachectl on boot. How do I change the service exe location to /etc/apache2/bin/apachectl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, /usr/sbin/service is just a wrapper for init.d scripts. Have a look at the file:

```
# A convenient wrapper for the /etc/init.d init scripts.
```

So, if your init.d uses apachectl, then service should use them too.

Comment: The help info that prints out if I just run sudo service apache2, is generated from httpd, `Usage: /etc/apache2/bin/httpd [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]`

Comment: Does `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 help` print that aswell?

Comment: Looks like it does, I'll have to figure out what's really going on then. Back to google with meeee. Thanks.